# Add Multiple Elements to Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a JQuery tooltip plugin and I am applying it to a few A tags.

For each A tag there should be a different tooltip associated with it so I have:

```
var $tooltip = $("<div>").attr("id", tooltip.id).attr("class", options.class).appendTo('body');
```

Where the tooltip id includes a random number created as follows:

```
id: "Tooltip_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (9999 - 2000 + 1) + 2000)
```

The plugin does not behave well. I checked the HTML added to the page.

Only one tooltip is being added to the page ... Always the same.

How can I fix this? What am I doing wrong? 
I have an example in: http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/wgapv

And the plugin code is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("table a").Tooltip(); 
});

// Tooltip
(function ($) {

  $.fn.Tooltip = function (options) {

    var defaults = {          
      class: 'Tooltip',
      delay: [200, 200],
      offset: [0, -10],
      hide: function ($element, $tooltip) {
        $tooltip.fadeOut(200);
      },
      show: function ($element, $tooltip) {
        $tooltip.fadeIn(200);
      }
    };

    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);   
    var tooltip = { id: "Tooltip_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (9999 - 2000 + 1) + 2000), ready: false, timer: null, title: '' };

    $(this).each(function (e) {     

      var $this = $(this);
      tooltip.title = $this.attr('title') || '';

      $this.mouseenter(function (e) {                  

        if (tooltip.ready) {
          var $tooltip = $("#" + tooltip.id);
        } else {
          var $tooltip = $("<div>").attr("id", tooltip.id).attr("class", options.class).appendTo('body');
          $tooltip.html(tooltip.title);
          tooltip.ready = true;
          $this.attr('title', '');
        }

        var position = [e.clientX + options.offset[0], e.clientY + options.offset[1]];

        $tooltip.css({ left: position[0] + 'px', top: position[1] + 'px' });

        tooltip.timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
          options.show($this, $tooltip.stop(true, true));
        }, options.delay[0] || 0);

        $("#" + tooltip.id).mouseenter(function () {
          window.clearTimeout(tooltip.timer);
          tooltip.timer = null;
        }); // Tooltip enter

        $("#" + tooltip.id).mouseleave(function () {
          tooltip.timer = setTimeout(function () {
            options.hide($this, $tooltip);
          }, 0);
        });

      }), // Mouse enter

      $this.mouseleave(function (e) {
        tooltip.timer = setTimeout(function () {
          options.hide($this, $("#" + tooltip.id).stop(true, true));
        }, options.delay[1] || 0);
      }) // Mouse leave  

    }); // Each

  }; // Tooltip

})(jQuery); // JQuery
```

And the HTMl is the following:

```
<table>
  <tr><td><a href="#" title="Tooltip 01 Text">Tooltip 01</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="#" title="Tooltip 02 Text">Tooltip 02</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="#" title="Tooltip 03 Text">Tooltip 03</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="#" title="Tooltip 04 Text">Tooltip 04</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="#" title="Tooltip 05 Text">Tooltip 05</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You've defined the `tooltip` object outside of your `.each()` and so you only have one instance of it shared between all of the links. Moving that inside the .each() will be a start but I don't know if that'll solve everything.

Answer (score 0):

you have the `var tooltip` definded outside the `this.each` loop, which means there will be only one `tooltip` instance

```
(function ($) {

  $.fn.Tooltip = function (options) {

    var defaults = {          
      class: 'Tooltip',
      delay: [200, 200],
      offset: [0, -10],
      hide: function ($element, $tooltip) {
        $tooltip.fadeOut(200);
      },
      show: function ($element, $tooltip) {
        $tooltip.fadeIn(200);
      }
    };

    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);   

    $(this).each(function (e) {     
        //moved this inside the loop
        var tooltip = { id: "Tooltip_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (9999 - 2000 + 1) + 2000), ready: false, timer: null, title: '' };

      var $this = $(this);
      tooltip.title = $this.attr('title') || '';

      $this.mouseenter(function (e) {                  

        if (tooltip.ready) {
          var $tooltip = $("#" + tooltip.id);
        } else {
          var $tooltip = $("<div>").attr("id", tooltip.id).attr("class", options.class).appendTo('body');
          $tooltip.html(tooltip.title);
          tooltip.ready = true;
          $this.attr('title', '');
        }

        var position = [e.clientX + options.offset[0], e.clientY + options.offset[1]];

        $tooltip.css({ left: position[0] + 'px', top: position[1] + 'px' });

        tooltip.timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
          options.show($this, $tooltip.stop(true, true));
        }, options.delay[0] || 0);

        $("#" + tooltip.id).mouseenter(function () {
          window.clearTimeout(tooltip.timer);
          tooltip.timer = null;
        }); // Tooltip enter

        $("#" + tooltip.id).mouseleave(function () {
          tooltip.timer = setTimeout(function () {
            options.hide($this, $tooltip);
          }, 0);
        });

      }), // Mouse enter

      $this.mouseleave(function (e) {
        tooltip.timer = setTimeout(function () {
          options.hide($this, $("#" + tooltip.id).stop(true, true));
        }, options.delay[1] || 0);
      }) // Mouse leave  

    }); // Each

  }; // Tooltip

})(jQuery);
```

Demo: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/arunpjohny/pen/zjpGe)

Comment: I updated my example according to your suggestion and it helps but I get another problem ... Sometimes I am able to show two tooltips at the same time ... And when I move the mouse away only one disappears. Is there a way to Hide all tooltips which are not associated to the link where the mouse is over. Does this make sense? It is just that the behavior at the moment is a little bit strange.